# DNN Fresh Install. Cannot get to Homepage

Tags: jquery, popup, dotnetnuke

I have installed DotNetNuke 7.03.01 on a Windows 2008 R2 server running IIS 7

The installation went ahead smoothly but when I opened the site and went to Login i got the 404 error page.

So I used the siturl/login.aspx to login to the site. Once I did the getting started popup keeps flashing infinitely and i cannot get further. If I check the console, I get

```
JQMIGRATE: Logging is active jquery-migrate.js?cdv=23:21
GET http://www.siteurl.org/DesktopModules/InternalServices/API/GettingStarted/GetGettingStartedPageSettings 401 (Unauthorized) jquery.js?cdv=23:8526
GET http://www.siteurl.org/DesktopModules/InternalServices/API/GettingStarted/GetContentUrl 401 (Unauthorized) jquery.js?cdv=23:8526
JQMIGRATE: Logging is active jquery-migrate.js?cdv=23:21
```

I don't know what could be causing this. I'm sure its a minor issue but unfortunately I cannot pinpoint it and there are not any resources that can help. Hopefully somebody has encountered this issue and has a solution for me.

Comment: i have also faced similar issue with this version of dnn later on i have installed 7.0.1 version it is working good you can download from this site https://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/releases/view/100069

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this problem resolved from the following link...

https://dnntracker.atlassian.net/browse/DNN-4264

So the simple solution is to add the following line to the modules node in the `web.config` file

```
runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"
```

So the modules node should look like this.

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
   <--->
   <--->
</modules>
```

Hopefully this answer should anybody else who encounters this problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an 'unauthorized' message, sounds like it could be a permissions issue.  You'll need to set permissions on the files system (the website folder).

From the DotNetNuke Install page (http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/loc/print/page/install_dotnetnuke):

> add the application pool ie; "IIS AppPool{AppPoolName}" (without the quotes). The application pool should be given modify permissions. The application pool should be given modify permissions

Check your Application Pool to see what account it is using.  Ex. If it is using NETWORKSERVICE account, you'll need to set permissions on the website folder to give that account modify access.